# nginx wordpress proxy_pass blog to another server

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, url-rewriting

Have 2 web servers.

Main for our project on nginx + php-fpm
And second for WordPess with same services.

In main nginx i have rule something like that

```
    location /blog { 
          proxy_pass http://someiporhostname:80;
    }
```

And it's work for me, but if url maindomain.com/blog/index.php - i not transfer to second server and stay at main.
I have blog/wp-admin to with redirect loop. cuz it's not try index.

i try to add some rules on location, try index. but nothing helps

Comment: First switch your error log to "debug" then confirm this location block is being matched.  My guess is you have another .php block that is matching first.